# Rowspace vs column space

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook states:

If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix such that rowspace($A$) = columnspace($A$), then $m = n$.

Why must this be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rowspace is spanned by the rows, and each row is an $n$-vector, hence an element of $\mathbb R^n$. Similarly, each column is an $m$-vector. If the spans are the same, then the rowspace and columnspace must be subspaces of the same space, hence $m = n$.

Comment: How do we know they are subspaces of the same space (since we only know that they are same subspace)? That's what I'm missing.

Comment: Ah, now I see it.